# How do I resolve a UnicodeDecodeError when using the .replace() function in python?

Tags: python

The error message is:

```
File "", line 23, in <module>
    line = file.readline().replace('\n','')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 180: character maps to <undefined>
```

It was working moments before and seemingly changed for no reason. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to [edit] to provide a [mcve]: the code you used to read the file and the sample input file. As to "*It was working moments before...*", either you changed the code or something changed in the file.